# Alternate row color for a wrappanel

Tags: wpf, wrappanel

I am trying to get an alternate row color effect on a Listbox / wrappanel. However since the orientation is Horizontal, The alternate columns are getting the alternate colors. I want the elements to be listed side ways and then wrapped. How can I set the alternate color on rows based on this.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MySource}"  ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource alternatingListItemStyle}" AlternationCount="2">
 <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
     <ItemsPanelTemplate>
         <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" MaxWidth="300"/>
     </ItemsPanelTemplate>
 </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
 <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
         <CheckBox Content="{Binding MyCaption}"/>
     </DataTemplate>
 </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

The possible reason for alternating color for columns is the 'MaxWidth'.
As the MaxWidth for WrapPanel is 300, it's possible to hold more than one item.
If you reduce the maxwidth, it may hold a single item.
Hope this helps.

(Can you explain why you are using a wrap panel in ItemsPanelTemplate?
I am not sure how you want the output to look like.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I set the MaxWidth so I can get the items to populate sideways before it populates the next row. Example if I have items A,B,C,D,E,F  and assuming only 3 can fit in a line, I want A, B, C to be in row one in one color and D,E,F in the next row with another background color. If there was a third row, it will repeat the color of the first row.